# How Can I Convert Less To Css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, less

I want to use "bootstrap.css" with only one div that its id is "DivSignature" and for that reason I want to create a new "bootstrap.css" with a different name that is arranged for my div.

For doing that i want to add "#DivSignature" prefix in all "bootstrap.css" properties(for example #DivSignature body {}).

And i decide to use "Less" for doing that solution.I prepared a Less file that named "Signature.less" and I want to convert my Less file to CSS with an online converter.

But I take error when i want to compile.Is my code wrong?

Can you help me to fix that error?I added my code below.
Thanks in Advance.

***Signature.less***

```css
#divSignature
{
    @import (less) url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}
```

Comment: where is your css code the above link?

Comment: **[Literally 5 seconds on google](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/less-to-css.html)**.

Comment: First of all don't use the minified version of the css there (use `...css/bootstrap.css` instead). Then make sure you set certain Less options required to compile external css w/o semantical changes (e.g. `--strict-math=on`). And finally be prepared to certain styles not working that way - Boostrap do put some styles on `html ...` and `body ...` and here they will become  `#divSignature html ...` and `#divSignature body ...` -> fail.

Comment: I serached a lot about that issue,but i cant find anything @Synch

Comment: And when you get a error, *always* put the error message into your post (we're not telepaths here - we can't know what "that error" is - and even if in this particular case it's not that hard to guess - it's still weird)

Answer (score 0):

First of all validate your less file & fix issues relates to -moz styling.
then convert it to css & you are good to go.

Comment: Ok,but how can i validate my less file?What is the true writing of the less code?

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/less-compiler.html  format you code & compile here..

following error found - 

Unable to compile any LESS input. SyntaxError: expected ')' got 's' in /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/tmp9119894989422279240less.tmp on line 2989, column 9: 2988 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; 2989 charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http: //www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"); 2990 }